# Кроссплатформенный способ узнать тип диска в Qt

Tags: qt5

Можно ли выяснить тип диска (removable, CD-ROM и прочие) в Qt?

Comment: Концепция «диска» это уже не кроссплатформенно, так что в Qt Вы вряд ли найдёте искомое.

Comment: в Qt нет. QStorageInfo это не умеет. Поэтому вероятнее всего самостоятельно реализовывайте решение под требуемые ОС.